# Semantics Invariants of Turbofan Sea-of-Nodes IR

Tags: javascript, v8, jit

I am studying Turbofan of Google V8.

I know it optimizes javascript code to machine code through lots of reductions.

I wonder if there exist some invariants about the semantic equivalence between each reduction.

While printing the IR between reductions, I observed a code snippet like the one below.

It connects 'Dead' operator to 'End' which is different from the original code semantics.

```
#47:Dead()
#50:IfTrue(#47:Dead)
#48:IfFalse(#47:Dead)
#51:Merge(#50:IfTrue, #48:IfFalse)
#52:Return(#51:Merge)
#53:End(#52:Return)
```

This is the original javascript code, and the above IR is optimized one for the function `v0`.

```
function main() {
  function v0(){}
function v0(v1,v2) {
    const v4 = -1.7976931348623157e+308 + v1;
    const v5 = v2 >= v1;
    if (v5) {
        const v7 = 2784663676 >= 2784663676;
        if (v7) {
            const v8 = ++v1;
        } else {
            const v9 = v2 ^ -1.7976931348623157e+308;
        }
    } else {
        const v10 = -1.7976931348623157e+308 > -1.7976931348623157e+308;
    }
    if (v5) {
        return -128;
        const v12 = v2 >= v1;
        let v13 = v5 ? v2 : v1;
        const v14 = v13 > -128;
        const v15 = v14 ? v13 : -128;
        const v16 = --v13;
    } else {
        const v17 = v2 < v2;
        const v18 = 770699.7300170623;
        const v19 = v1 * v1;
        const v20 = -536870912;
        const v21 = v17 ? v2 : v2;
    }
}
for(var i=0;i<50000;i++){
    const v17 = v0(1.5,-0.0);
  }
}
%NeverOptimizeFunction(main);
main();
```

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder if there exist some invariants about the semantic equivalence between each reduction.

Yes, of course: like any compiler, Turbofan must not change the behavior of the program, so all of its reductions must be semantics-preserving.

The only footnote is that Turbofan can rely on deoptimizations: for various reasons (e.g. lack of type feedback), it can decide to not emit code for a given case, and emit a deopt point instead.

> While printing the IR between reductions, I observed a code snippet like the one below.

That IR is not what I'm getting when tracing Turbofan for the code snippet you provided. In fact, I'm not seeing any "Dead" nodes. That said, there is dead code in that JS function, so it's not surprising that Turbofan recognizes that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I printed the code snippet by inserting the graph printing code to `Reduce` function in src/compiler/graph-reducer.cc. Maybe I think I printed the graph while the reduction is processing. Can I ask the minimum unit of semantics-preserving at the source code level?

Comment: @강우석 The flag `--trace-turbo-graph` needs no source modifications. -- Not sure I understand the question. Semantics of a function need to be preserved.

Comment: I understand that `--tracer-turbo-graph` flag prints the graph phase by phase(e.g. SimplifiedLowering, EarlyOptimization, ...). However, each phase contains many reduction steps, and I want to know how they change the graph. That's why I modify the source code to print the graph before reduction and after reduction. Does that mean that the semantics of a function are preserved in each reduction unit?

Comment: @강우석 Yes, every reducer preserves semantics of every function. Anything else would be a bug.